# Are questions on blockchains on topic?

Tags: discussion, tags

Just wondering if questions regarding blockchain technology are on topic?

From the [help link](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> This site covers theoretical and applied computer science at any level..

I'd categorise blockchains as applied computer science, and there are a few questions on it already, so I'd say questions are on topic. Perhaps unless the question relates to some specific implementation problem. If it is on topic, would blockchain be worthy of a tag? Or are there adequate synonyms?

Comment: Are you asking about the "blockchains" being on-topic here or suggest creating a tag?

Comment: Concepts, yes; technology, probably not so much. What, specifically do you have in mind? Note that there are [cryptography.SE] and [security.SE], both of which probably have a wealth of material on blockchains.

Comment: @Evil both - I should have been clearer

Comment: @Raphael I'd like to compare existing blockchain protocols, so questions around the language and concepts I might use.